# "Sales Badge" without sale price on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on woocommerce on wordpress, I want to make some sale badges but ignore the sales price (there are only regular prices).

I've tried it several times but the "sale badge" can only appear when I put the number on the sale price on the product

I use the code below

```
  add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'woocommerce_custom_sale_text', 10, 3);
function woocommerce_custom_sale_text($text, $post, $_product)
{
    global $post,$product;
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) return;
    $sale_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_price', true);
    $regular_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_regular_price', true);
    if (has_term('one', 'product_cat', $product->ID)) {
        return '<span class="onsale">one</span>';
    } elseif (has_term('two', 'product_cat', $product->ID)) {
        return '<span class="onsale">two</span>';
    } elseif (has_term('three', 'product_cat', $product->ID) || empty($sale_price)) {
        return '<span class="onsale">three</span>';
    }
    return '<span class="onsale">Sale</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter itself is applied only if the product is on sale.

You need to overwrite the flash sale actions that happen before checking if the product is on sale.

first, remove the core flash sale hooks.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash', 10 );
```

then, add your custom sale function instead.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_custom_sale_text', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_custom_sale_text', 10 );
```

then use `echo` instead of `return`

```
function woocommerce_custom_sale_text()
{
    global $post,$product;
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) return;
    $sale_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_price', true);
    $regular_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_regular_price', true);
    if (has_term('one', 'product_cat', $product->ID)) {
        echo '<span class="onsale">one</span>';
    } elseif (has_term('two', 'product_cat', $product->ID)) {
        echo '<span class="onsale">two</span>';
    } elseif (has_term('three', 'product_cat', $product->ID) || empty($sale_price)) {
        echo '<span class="onsale">three</span>';
    }
    echo '<span class="onsale">Sale</span>';
}
```